# How to get reference to parent class subroutine perl

Tags: perl, oop, inheritance, reference

I have a situation where in child class, I need a reference of subroutines defined in parent class which I need to pass to some other class which would execute them.
So I was wrote following sample modules for testing the same.

## Parent1.pm

```
package Parent1;

sub new {
    my ($class, $arg_hash) = @_;

    my $self = bless $arg_hash, $class; 

    return $self;
}

sub printHello{

    print "Hello\n";
}

sub printNasty{
    print "Nasty\n";
}
1;
```

## Child1.pm

```
package Child1; 

use base Parent1;

sub new {
    my ($class, $arg_hash) = @_;

    my $self = bless $arg_hash, $class; 

    return $self;
}

sub testFunctionReferences{

    my ($self) = @_;

    # Case 1: Below 2 lines of code doesn't work and produces error message "Not a CODE reference at Child1.pm line 18."
    #my $parent_hello_reference = \&$self->SUPER::printHello;
    #&$parent_hello_reference();

    # Case 2: Out of below 2 lines of code, 1st line executes the function and produces output of "Hello\n" but 2nd line doesn't work and produces error message "Not a CODE reference at Child1.pm line 23."
    #my $parent_hello_reference2 = \$self->SUPER::printHello;
    #&$parent_hello_reference2();

    # Case 3: does not work either. Says "Undefined subroutine &Child1::printNasty called at Child1.pm line 27"
    #my $parent_nasty_reference = \&printNasty;
    #&$parent_nasty_reference();

    # Case 4: works. prints "World\n" as expected  
    #my $my_own_function_reference = \&printWorld;
    #&$my_own_function_reference();

    # Case 5: works. prints "Hello\n" and  "Nasty\n" as expected
    #$self->printHello();
    #$self->SUPER::printNasty();

    # Case 6: does not work produces error "Undefined subroutine &Child1::printHello called at Child1.pm line 38" 
    #printHello();
    return;
}

sub printWorld{
    print "World\n";
}
```

## test.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Child1;

my $child = Child1->new({});

$child->testFunctionReferences();
```

So my questions are:

1. As in case 1, what is the correct syntax to get a reference to parent subroutine?
2. When I use inheritance, how can I call the parent function directly as in case 6? Is it even possible in perl?
3. When case 5 works then why not case 6?

Any insights are appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `printHello` is a subroutine, use

```
my $sub = \&Parent::printHello;
```

---

If `printHello` is a method, use

```
# This line must appear inside of the Child package.
my $sub = sub { $self->SUPER::method(@_) };
```

If you want a code reference, you need a subroutine to reference, and this creates one.

---

In both cases, you can call the sub using

```
&$sub();
```

or

```
$sub->();
```

(I find the latter cleaner, but they are otherwise equivalent.)

Comment: Thanks.First case works and I understood it as well. But can you please explain what's being done in case of method and how to interpret that code? And also can we avoid passing @_?

Comment: It's an anon sub that consist of a method call.  It's a *closure* that *captures* `$self`, so it works even if you return it and $self is no longer in scope

Answer (score 1):

I figured out another method to get a reference to a parent class subroutine using 'UNIVERSAL' module 'can' method.

```
#Parent.pm

        package Parent;

        sub new {
            my ($class, $arg_hash) = @_;
            my $self = bless $arg_hash, $class; 
            return $self;
        }

        sub printHello{
            print "Parent Hello Called\n";
        }

        1;


#Child.pm
        package Child;
        use base Parent;

        sub new {
            my ($class, $arg_hash) = @_;
            my $self = bless $arg_hash, $class; 
            return $self;
        }

        sub getParentSubReference{
            my ($self) = @_;
            return $self->can('printHello');
        }  

        1;


#test.pl

        #!/usr/bin/perl
        use Child;

        my $obj = Child->new({});
        my $ref = $obj->getParentSubReference();
        &$ref();


#Output
        Parent Hello Called
```